# Delete row in TableView and remove the core data - iOS / Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode6, delete-row

I am having an issue with my swift app. I am trying to implement the swipe feature that will prompt the user with the "DELETE" option. As of right now my code only allows me to swipe but the delete button is not being generated. I am currently using Xcode 6.3.2 as well.

**Thank you in advance**!

```
import UIKit // apples code for all UI related code
import AVFoundation // apple's code for audio and video
import CoreData


class SoundListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer() // creating an audio player property as the variable audioplayer

var sounds : [Sound] = [] // creating an array to hold all sounds, in swift you need to tell the array what it will be holding, this is done by ": [Sound]" this tells the array that it will contain Sound objects


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // comment
    self.tableView.dataSource = self // added to make the Table view work
    self.tableView.delegate = self // added to make the Table view work


}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // comment

    var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Sound") // allows to go get all the objects stored in core data
    self.sounds = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)! as! [Sound]
    self.tableView.reloadData()


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.sounds.count // # of rows we want the table view to have based on the contents of sounds array
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var sound = self.sounds[indexPath.row] // searches the index path of each row from the array of sounds and stores to the varibale sounds once it has the correct object
    var cell = UITableViewCell() // each cell on the table
    cell.textLabel!.text = sound.name // adds the correct name from each object to the correct row

    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0){ // adding color to each cell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }else if (indexPath.row % 2 != 0){
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    return cell // printing the new data into each cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    var sound = self.sounds[indexPath.row]

    var baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String

    var pathComponents = [baseString, sound.url]

    var audioNSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)

    self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioNSURL, error: nil) // play command while asking for where the audio lives

    self.audioPlayer.play() // play audio command on click

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){
        sounds.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row) // array of objects that we are selecting
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation:.Fade)
        self.tableView.reloadData()// updated table view

    }
}

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! newSoundViewContoller
    nextViewController.soundListViewController = self

}
}
```

Comment: Have a look at NSFetchedResultsController it's what you need to be using with a UITableView and CoreData. It does all the deleting and updating stuff too. Have a search on the Ray Wenderlich site.

Comment: @Fogmeister, Thank you I will read his article. Do you know if this is the cause of my issue? I mean I am very much a novice swift developer and I figured that tableView would have a delete method build in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The issue with my delete was not the issue. (**NOTE**: you do not need the "tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation:.Fade)" line in your delete function.)

The issue I was originally having was that the slide would work but the user would not be prompt with the delete.

Make sure you check your constraints with your tableView. Also make sure you uncheck the "Constraint to margins" option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't find your issues specifically but. Here is some code that worked for me. Let me know if it works for you.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel!.text = "Delete me!"
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){
        println("DELETED")
    }
}
}
```